# Задать определеный тип переменной в массиве object

Tags: c#

Есть:

```
object[] item = new object[6];
```

Можно ли указать для каждого элемента массива тип переменной

Comment: А зачем? Что не устраивает просто заносить то, что необходимо?

Comment: в массиве - никак,они и существуют чтобы хранить объекты 1 тип данных

Comment: А зачем в массиве хранить разнородные типы данных? Можно воспользоваться Dictionary<object,Type>. Получается объект и по значению приводить к нужному типу, но все равно извращение.

Comment: Для хранения группы переменных различного типа используют структуры или классы.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нет. Тип данных является "общим" для всех элементов массива. Поэтому, в частности когда Вы будете добавлять в массив `object` любые данные они будут автоматически приводиться к `object` и при извлечении Вам скорее всего по любому придётся приводить их обратно.

Если Вы хотите оперировать с данными сложной структуры, используйте классы.

Answer (score 3):

Подозреваю, что хочется передавать какой-то набор данных, но не хочется под него выделять отдельный тип.

В таком случае удобными могут оказаться кортежи, в них как раз указывается тип каждого элемента.

Пример:

```
(int, double, string, StringBuilder, MyType) tuple = (5, 10.2, "hello", new StringBuilder(), new MyType());
```